# Can't directly open whatsapp chat group invite

Tags: ios, flutter, whatsapp, url-scheme

I need to open a whatsapp chat group link invite (https://chat.whatsapp.com/############) from my flutter app without opening the browser first. just using url_launcher and launch('https://chat.whatsapp.com/############') works on android, but on IOS it opens Safari first.

I had the same problem for telegram, but I found this: tg://join?invite=XXXXXX, which I'm 99% sure it will work for IOS, but I didn't find anything similar for Whatsapp, except for Whatsapp://send= but it doesn't work to open the invite

Comment: Which iOS version are you trying, I tried it now on 13.5 and it's working.

Comment: Also do you have latest Whatsapp version?

Comment: Yes I do, I don't believe it has to do with Whatsapp version since I had the same problem on telegram, but to solve it just needed to use the URL scheme tg://join?invite=

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your first question, I'll check

Comment: Can you confirm that the new solution works for you.

Comment: I don't have an IOS with me, waiting for my boss to test it, I'll let you know and confirm your answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For universal links to work with `url_launcher` on iOS you need to pass the `forceSafariVC` param as false so that it doesn't open the Safari view first:

```
launch(url, forceSafariVC: false);
```

Comment: Please read the question, I don't want to send a message to one user, I want to open a group invite.

Comment: Sorry the delay, Worked very well now, thank you very much!